# Onresize event on Image inside a Dojo Content Pane

Tags: javascript, html, dojo

I have a Dojo Content Layout Pane on my Page and inside that there is an image which is being formed inside my Python code. The images is made from multiple small segments. Now what I have to do is to show different tooltips on different segments of the image. What I did was that I associated the image to a  and each area has different tooltip. Now the problem is that when the Content Pane is resized, then it resizes the image as well but the coordinates in  remain the same so the tooltips get screwed up. Is there any way to change the  coordinates when the resizing is done? Because what I think is that when resizing is being done, then DOJO is handling it and the internal onresize event us not triggered.

Comment: Can you post how your tooltips are being created? Or perhaps if you can create a fiddle as an example that would be even better. I think the tooltips should be mapped to a certain dom node (which should be the image) but there could be something else at play here

Comment: I figured it out. Used the onmouseover event for the dynamic tooltip generation.

Comment: Dojo's Content pane call resize method of each of the child widget's when its resized. So I think you will have to handled the coordinates part in the widget that will have to generate the image with the segments!!